# What's the best way to "secure pseudo stream" mp4 videos (flash, html5, pc, iOS...)?

Tags: ios, html, streaming, mp4, jwplayer

I'm looking for a way to allow my customers (logged in) to watch mp4 videos on my website.

- I don't want them to be able to download the video, or at least make it very difficult.
- The server is linux / the app is PHP
- I want my customers to be able to watch the videos on a computer web brower or on an iOS/Safari device (which means no flash).
- I need it to be free or really cheap (not hosting videos on a cloud base provider for thousands of dollars each month for example).

Until now I was doing the following :

- php pseudo streaming of flv files (known as xmoov). Using php I was able to perform secure verifications before returning the content of the stream (sessions variables, token,...) But it's not working on iOS because of flv videos need flash to be played. It is also not so secure because a simple firefox extension like Video Download Helper can download them.
- so I encoded my videos in mp4, which works fine with html5/iOS but makes the "secure" aspect of the process a lot harder : it seems very hard to make php pseudo streaming. I haven't found any working solution, and it seems that everybody goes away from it because it takes too much ressources (1 php process for each video during the streaming of the whole file content).

So the best solution I found is the 2 classical Apache plugins : "H264 Streaming Module" and "Mod Auth Token".
Ok, it's better, but it sems a dead end because to be efficient the timeout of the auth token needs to be very short (less than 5 seconds to make very difficult to find the obfuscated url in the html source and copy/paste it in a download application or starting a script or ...) but it means that the customer has to start the video within this time-frame (on iOS there is no way to autostart the video). It also mean that the customer is not able to seek in a "not already downloaded" part of the video, because the player (I use JWplayer) makes a new http call to the url, which obviously doesn't work anymore because of the timeout.

I was thinking about a video flash player which can generate the obfuscated url by itself (and not php outputting it in the html source) but it won't work on iOS because it's flash based. If I use this on computers and html5/auth_token on iOS (based on user agent) it's very easy to spoof the user agent and download the videos.

An other solution seems to use a "real" video streaming server, like Red5, but almost every tutorial I found is about live streaming, tv's, webcam, and not simple mp4 files sitting on a hard drive. It also seems to be not the application made for this type of need.

So I'm open to every suggestion !

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is why digital rights management (DRM) has been invented. You got lots of options on the browser side but none is free or cheap or is working for browser AND iOS out of the box (MS PlayReady / Flash Access). I would definitely go for a DRM provider like buydrm.com or wowza.com which seems to nicely integrate with buydrm.com

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out for FLV files using Amazon's S3:

http://evolt.org/s3secure

I'm working on doing it for MP4, but my expertise is web stuff, not video stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself in the same situation.

I'm using flowplayer, and I get FLVs to pseudo stream fine using a server side (PHP) script, similar to xmoov one, with all the validations you mention.

**I have 1 tip for you:**
I'm using, **IF $start is 0**, the token works only for *3 seconds* (so no new requests can be made), but **IF $start is > 0**, then it works for 10 mins, or a little more.

This way, people will be able to seek to other parts of the video, but not to make a full request. You could also make this $start limit greater than X bytes, instead of >0, to make sure smart guys doesn't skip your validation.

Now, regarding MP4 pseudo-streaming using the same script, I'm still in trouble.
as $start value is sent as seconds (i.e: ?start=32.125), instead of bytes position, I can't seem to make the video pseudostream.

If you found a solution (without more than mod_h264_streaming), i'll be glad to hear it.